# Adopting a TikZ figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please look at this MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\test}[3][1]{%
    % #1 = optional height
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \Stop/\Nenner/\Options/\Number [count=\c] in {#3} {
    % Abstand zwischen Zeilen % {#1*\c} altern.
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\YCoord}{1.75*\c} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xincrement}{#2/10}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Zincrement}{#2/\Nenner}
    
    \foreach \x in {1,...,10} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xcoord}{\x*\Xincrement}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\XcoordLabel}{(\x-0.5)*\Xincrement}
        %Farbe
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\XCoordFill}{ifthenelse(\x > \Stop, "none", "\Options")}
        %\pgfmathsetmacro{\XCoordFill}{white}
        \draw[fill=white] 
        ($(\Xcoord-\Xincrement,-\YCoord)$) rectangle ($(\Xcoord,-\YCoord+#1)$);
        \node at ($(\x*\Xincrement,-\YCoord-0.3)$) { {\footnotesize \x0 \%}};
        \node at ($(\x*\Xincrement,-\YCoord-0.6)$) { {\footnotesize von}};
        \node at ($(\x*\Xincrement,-\YCoord-0.9)$) { {\footnotesize \Number}};
    }%

    \foreach \z in {1,...,\Nenner} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Zcoord}{\z*\Zincrement}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ZcoordLabel}{(\z-0.5)*\Zincrement}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ZCoordFill}{ifthenelse(\z > \Stop, "none", "\Options")}
        \draw[draw=\ZCoordFill, fill=\ZCoordFill]
        ($(\Zcoord-\Zincrement,-\YCoord)$) rectangle ($(\Zcoord,-\YCoord+#1)$);
        \node at (\Stop/\Nenner*#2,-\YCoord+1.6) {{\footnotesize \Stop\% von \Number}};
    }
    }%      
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}
    
\test{14}{27/100/cyan/250}

\end{document}
```

It creates this picture:

[image]

Can you see the picture?

Anyway I have two problems left:

1. the above node (the last line in the code) has a strange font, but I don´t know why
2. I wish, that the blacklines appear on the entire figure, not just on the part next to the blue part

What I have to change?

Comment: To have the black lines cover the blue rectangle, you need to draw them after you draw the blue rectangle. The font looks strange, because you create multiple nodes with this text and at the same position.

Comment: @montarenbici: Can you update your question titles to be more reflective of what the question is? See, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/703192/5764, that has a very similar title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure whether I understand correctly what you want to achieve. Anyways, your two questions can be answered quite simply:

1. The strange font is because you print the same text multiple times (100 times, to be exact) at the same position. You probably don't want to use a `\foreach` loop to draw the cyan rectangle. At least, you don't need one.
2. If the black lines should cover the cyan rectangle, you need to typeset them afterwards. And you should not fill the rectangles you place later white, because this would, of course, cover the cyan rectangle and render it invisible.

So, this could maybe serve as starting point (there is no need to load the `calc` library here, as you can do basic calculations in coordinates directly):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\test}[3][1]{%
    % #1 = optional height
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \Stop/\Nenner/\Options/\Number [count=\c] in {#3} {
        % Abstand zwischen Zeilen % {#1*\c} altern.
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\YCoord}{1.75*\c} 
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xincrement}{#2/10}
        
        \draw[\Options, fill=\Options]
            (0,{-\YCoord}) rectangle ({\Stop/\Nenner*#2},{-\YCoord+#1});
        \node[above, font=\footnotesize] at ({\Stop/\Nenner*#2},{-\YCoord+#1}) 
            {\Stop\% von \Number};

        \foreach \x in {1,...,10} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xcoord}{\x*\Xincrement}
            \draw ({\Xcoord-\Xincrement},{-\YCoord}) rectangle ({\Xcoord},{-\YCoord+#1});
            \node[below, align=center, font=\footnotesize] at ({\x*\Xincrement},{-\YCoord}) 
                {\x0 \% \\ von \\ \Number};
        }
    }  
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
    
\test{14}{27/100/cyan/250}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code can surely be optimised, but as I am unsure of the real use case, I only edited as much as I thought was necessary.

Comment: Wow, that is perfect, exactly how I need it to be. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Another possibilities, with rewritten command for drawing your image from scratch with goal to make code simpler, shorter and easier to comprehend (this was easier than searching for the source of problem(s) in your code) .

In command are defined three styles for nodes, style for labels of nodes and new style for image title (by it are removed repetitions of of nodes labels, you may liked it). In definitions of styles are used Ti*k*Z libraries `backgrounds` (that bar can be beside percentage scale, `chains` (for draw sequence of nodes representing the percentage scale) and `positioning` (for support nodes placements):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                chains,
                positioning}
\newcommand{\test}[4][8]{% 1: optional nodes heights
                            % #2: length of higlighted part
                            % #3: color of heighlighting
                            % #4: number of samples
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 0mm,
  start chain = going right,
  base/.style = {minimum height=#1 mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
   lbl/.style = {text width=2.2em, align=center,
                 font=\scriptsize, text=red},
     M/.style = {base, %name=m,
                 draw, minimum width=10mm,
                 label = {[lbl, anchor=north]south east:\s\;\%},
                 node contents={}, on chain},
     P/.style = {base, minimum width=#2 mm, fill=#3,
                 label = {[lbl, anchor=south]north east:#2\;\%},
                 node contents={},
                 right=of m1.west},
     T/.style = {inner xsep=0pt, font=\bfseries, above right=of m1.north west},
                        ]
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\s}{int(10*\x)}
\node   (m\x) [M];
}
\node[T]    {percentages of number #4:};
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node   [P=#2/#3];
    \end{tikzpicture}
            }%  \test


\begin{document}
\test{27}{teal!30}{250}

\bigskip
\test[12]{27}{teal!30}{250}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case, that you not liked images titles, just remove `T` style definition and insertion of node `T`, and to labels in definition of `M` and `N` nodes add text `von #4:

```
\newcommand{\test}[4][8]{% 1: optional nodes heights
                            % #2: length of higlighted part
                            % #3: color of heighlighting
                            % #4: number of samples
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 0mm,
  start chain = going right,
  base/.style = {minimum height=#1 mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
   lbl/.style = {text width=2.2em, align=center,
                 font=\scriptsize, text=red},
     M/.style = {base, 
                 draw, minimum width=10mm,
                 label = {[lbl, anchor=north]south east:\s\;\% von #4},
                 node contents={}, on chain},
     P/.style = {base, minimum width=#2 mm, fill=#3,
                 label = {[lbl, anchor=south]north east:#2\;\% von #4},
                 node contents={},
                 right=of m1.west},
                        ]
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\s}{int(10*\x)}
\node   (m\x) [M];
}
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node   [P=#2/#3];
    \end{tikzpicture}
            }%  \test
```

After this changes you will get`

[image]

Comment: Well, thank you for your input, I really like your approach. For me as a beginner with TikZ it is really helpful to see something like that. But I wonder if another adjustment is possible? The distance between the vertical lines are always 10%, is it posilbe to adopt, that you can set this space manualy, for example 20 percent between the vertical lines, or 25%

Comment: In fact, 20% and 25% would be the most used cases.
If I adopt ``` \foreach \x in {1,...,5}
  {
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\s}{int(20*\x)}
   \node   (m\x) [M];
  }```
The numbers would be fine, but the blue bar is of the false size

Comment: @montarenbici, sorry, I do not understand your comments. If you. My solution for your command contain all main functionality of your definition. If you like to have different command features, please ask new question (with link to this one) where explain what command should do. However, you select another answer, so I expect that you will go with its solutions ...